# QGIS/OpenLayers - How to add a "labels-only" reference layer (basemap focused on labels)?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, basemap, plugins

In ArcGIS you can add a "reference basemap" which features labels for key locations as in:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8b3d38c0819547faa83f7b7aca80bd76

However, in QGIS, I can't figure out a way of achieving the same effect, even when using the OpenLayers plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google Streets is quite close to being a similar basemap which includes labels.

Comment: @Joseph: However, you cant use only its labels, can you? you have to show the image of the map too. I would love to use google`s labels. But I cant use its imagery.. as I already have rasters of my own to show. I plan on using the labels to better illustrate my map.

Comment: Ahh I get you now. I never came across this before so hopefully others can advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the labels use [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) to query the Openstreetmap data for what information you want. If you are new to this service or want a different way to do the same thing use the [Quick OSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) plugin to do the same (it in turn uses Overpass).

If you have some familiarity with OSM then this should be a relatively simple process - at least if you are looking for point data for cities, towns, suburbs, etc. You'd be looking for [places](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Places) I think: (place = country ; place = region ; place = city ; place = town ; etc). The data might need an edit... after all the location for such a point is going to be relatively arbitrary, and exactly what names fit what categories is often going to be a personal choice related to local circumstances.

Style the points to have a label but no marker. I've never done this but remember reading that it could be done - I think presumably by making a very small marker and/or covering it with the label.

Don't forget the [credit for this data](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) if the mapping is for distribution.

If you also need to generate a simple country/region outline you can probably get this [using the same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166419/how-to-download-the-county-boundaries-of-china-in-openstreetmap).

If you want is something more than this - perhaps a good map showing lots of detail but in grey and lacking many normal labels then you might need to look at more specific solutions or combinations of solutions. There's a pretty good chance that someone out there already has a style of Openstreetmap based mapping which does something like what you want. Check out [link1](https://www.mapbox.com/); [link2](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) and [link3](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM-based_services) to scratch the surface. Whether this is available for free, for a fee, or whether you need to get them to adapt it a little will require some research.